# Mépris de, mépris pour

Tags: sens

> Le mépris pour quelqu'un, le mépris de la vie.

ici le mépris est dirigé vers *quelqu'un* ou *la vie* pour leur dénier tout intérêt,
  mais :

> Le mépris de quelqu'un.

induit une réversibilité par l'échange du *pour* en *de* (réversibilité que *de la vie* ci-dessus n'a pas) :

- soit le mépris s'oriente comme dans la première phrase, vers *quelqu'un*,
- soit le mépris est un sentiment issu de *quelqu'un*.

1 - Comment appelle-t-on ce genre de phrases, chères aux oracles antiques et autres pythies.
2 - Quelles sont les signes, les alertes, les pressentiments, les intuitions qui indiqueraient que l'on emploie ces phrases sans s'en rendre compte ?
3 - À part dans les aphorismes et certains haïkus en rencontrez-vous souvent ?

4 - À part *de*, y a-t-il d'autres mots clefs pour de telles constructions ?

Comment: Une phrase ambigüe?

Comment: @Relaxed J'avais pensé à *double-sens* mais *ambiguë* (ancienne calligraphie) a aussi pour synonyme *équivoque, ambivalente* voire *obscure, double, incertaine* ; sinon ce sera *plurivoque, polysémique* pour les savants et *amphibologique* (sens ambigu) - selon le Robert. Pour la conversion *équivoque* ou *ambigu* et pour certains écrits *amphibologique* ce qui obligera quelques uns à rechercher dans le dictionnaire. Voilà une piste vraiment intéressante, merci.

Answer (score 2):

Je pense qu'il s'agit d'une ambiguïté sémantique, du genre: "Pierre sent la rose"
ou "Sylvain a vu un homme avec un télescope."